# How to perform file upload monitoring with Play! framework

Tags: java, playframework

Is it possible to monitor file uploads, somehow, with Play! framework? <del>Also, if the file should be BIG (i.e. +500MB), would it be possible to save the received bytes into a temporary file instead of keeping it in memory?</del> *(see update below)*

**note** : there is no code to show as I'm wondering these questions and cannot seem to find the answers with Google

Thanks!

** **Update** **

(I almost forgot about this question.) Well, apparantly, files uploaded *are* stored in temporary files, and the files are not passed as a byte array (or something), but as a [Java `File` object to the action controller](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/5things).

But even in a RESTful environment, file monitoring *can* be achieved.

** **Update 2** **

Is there a way to get early event listeners on incoming HTTP requests? This could allow for monitoring request data transfer.

Comment: I am starting to ask myself the same kind of questions. I'm gonna look into it.

Answer (score 2):

### Large requests and temp files

Play! is already storing large HTTP requests in temp files named after UUIDs (thus reducing the memory footprint of the server). Once the request is done, this file gets deleted.

### Monitoring uploads in Play!

Play! is using (the awesome) [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) project for its HTTP server stack (and also on the client stack, if you're considering [Async HTTP client](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client).

Netty is:

- asynchronous
- event-driven
- 100% HTTP

Given Play!'s stack, you *should be able* to implement your "upload progress bar" or something. Actually, Async HTTP client already achieves **progress listeners for file uplaods** and **resumable download** (see the [quick start guide](https://github.com/sonatype/async-http-client/blob/master/docs/AHCQuickStartGuide.pdf)).

**But** [play.server](https://github.com/playframework/play/tree/master/framework/src/play/server) package doesn't seem to provide such functionality/extension point.

### Monitoring uploads anyway

I think Play! is meant to be behind a "real" HTTP server in reverse proxy mode (like nginx or lighthttpd).

So you'd better off using an upload progress module for one of those servers (like [HttpUploadProgressModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpUploadProgressModule) for nginx) than messing with Play!'s HTTP stack.

Comment: yes, Netty *is* awesome. I never do Java network apps w/o it since about 2-3 years now. I have seen documentation using "real" HTTP servers as load balancers, but I believe that the full stack *can* be used as is in production regardless if it's behind another server or answering directly through the HTTP ports (never seen anywhere in the official doc discouraging it). The idea of using another server to handle the upload is probably what people do usually (using Python, or something), but I'm more interested in a Play! only solution. I guess it would have to be a core feature, then...